# Can't insert into mysql from html multiple option form using php

Tags: php, html, mysql, html-select

I'm quite new to this, so sorry if this is a very easy question. When i try to insert into mysql using a multiple option html form it only inserts the last option selected from the drop down list, but inserts that option multiple times.

HTML

```
<form action ="test_page.php" method="post">
     <select name= fruit[] size="8" multiple>
         <option value ="Apples" >Apples</option>
         <option value ="Oranges" >Oranges</option>
         <option value ="Bananas" >Bananas</option>
         <option value ="Grapes" > Grapes </option>
         <option value ="Strawberries"> Strawberries</option>
    </select>
    <br><br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>`
```

And here's the PHP

```
<?php

foreach ($_POST["fruit"] as $favourite)
{
    $sql = "INSERT INTO Fruit_table (Apples, Oranges, Bananas, Grapes) VALUES ('$favourite','$favourite','$favourite', '$favourite');";
}

if ($conn->multi_query($sql) === TRUE)  {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>"  .  $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: you need to run the query in the loop or concatenate the query to run once, currently you overwrite $sql in the loop, which is why you only get the last one

Comment: **Warning:** You are wide open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should really use parameterized [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of manually building your queries like that. Specially since you're not escaping the user inputs at all! This is _extra_ important when using multi-query since anyone pass a complete SQL statement that wipes your entire DB.

Comment: The query looks pretty strange as well. You're adding new rows for each fruit and you set all the columns to the same value?

Comment: There's absolutely no reason to use `multi_query` here when you have one query.

Comment: A schema like this is a pretty clear violation of the [Zero, One or Infinity Rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_one_infinity_rule) of
[database normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization). If possible try and restructure this into a one-to-many relational structure as that will make your data a lot easier to work with once inserted.

Answer (score -2):

Add quotes around the name.

From this:

```
<select name=fruit[] size="8" multiple>
```

to this:

```
<select name="fruit[]" size="8" multiple>
```

Comment: Actually, it will work without the quotes as well. The OP also says that only the last selected item get's inserted, which means that the form _does_ post it properly and that the issue is in the PHP code.

Answer (score -2):

I found your problem!
So, you are actually setting `$sql` multiple times with the `foreach` while only executing the last one.

So like this;

```
foreach ($_POST["fruit"] as $favourite)
{
$sql = "INSERT INTO Fruit_table (Apples, Oranges, Bananas, Grapes) 
 VALUES ('$favourite','$favourite','$favourite', '$favourite');";
}
```

This is the full **working** code!

```
<?php

foreach ($_POST["fruit"] as $favourite)
{
$sql = "INSERT INTO Fruit_table (Apples, Oranges, Bananas, Grapes) 
 VALUES ('$favourite','$favourite','$favourite', '$favourite');";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE)  {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>"  .  $conn->error;
}
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

So, I only changed until where the `foreach()` will be. This should work now!

Comment: Still uses `multi_query` for no reason, and now has a working SQL injection hole instead of a broken one. "Working" means "by the book", not "may function under an extremely narrow set of circumstances, and has side effects which may include losing control of your database and/or your company".

Comment: This code doesn't even solve the problem, it now inserts N records, one per thing checked, all of which have all columns populated.